# Timeout a query

Tags: sql, mysql, ado.net

I wanted to know if we can timeout a sql query.

In the sense, that suppose I have a sql query whose output is useful only if gives the output in 10 minutes ,after which even if it outputs the results its of no use to me.

What I want to do is that if the query takes more than 10 minutes to do the processing then it should just kind of kill itself.

Is there a possible way to do so??

An example will be pretty helpful.

Let me know if my thoughts are not comprehendible..

Comment: if a query takes 10 minutes then either (a) you have a very large database, (b) you have the mother of all queries (unlikely), or (c) you need to re-evaluate your indexes. My money is on (c)

Comment: 10 min was just a random val i took for example.. u can think of any time

Comment: If a query takes more than 30 seconds, I would be looking at it...

Comment: well I have a real huge database

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's what it would look like for the [SqlCommand.CommandTimeout](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.commandtimeout%28v=VS.100%29.aspx)

```
   SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
   cmd.CommandText = "SELECT blah FROM Categories ORDER BY CategoryID";
   cmd.CommandTimeout = 600;  // 10 minutes = 600 seconds
   // Caveat: it you need a timeout value of more than 30 - 60 seconds
   //         perhaps time to look at why it takes so long...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set the `CommandTimout` property of the `Command` object to 10 minutes.  When the command times out, SQL Server will notice that the connection is dropped and cancel the query.

Comment: can u provide an example .. will be of a lot of help